# Data is mutated but not updated in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a sever connected to a mongodb database. When I add a first level data and then save that, it works.

For example :

```js
// this works fine

router.post('/user/addsomedata', async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({email : req.body.email})
        user.username = req.body.username
        await user.save()
        res.send()
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(404).send(e)
    }
})
```

BUT if I try to save the object with deeper level data, it's not getting saved. I guess the update is not detected and hence the user didn't get replaced.

Example :

```js
router.post('/user/addtask', auth ,async (req,res)=>{
    const task = new Task({
        name : req.body.name,
        timing : new Date(),
        state : false,
    })
    try {
        const day = await req.user.days.find((day)=> day.day == req.body.day)
        // day is found with no problem
        req.user.days[req.user.days.indexOf(day)].tasks.push(task)
        // console.log(req.user) returns exactly the expected results
        await req.user.save(function(error,res){
            console.log(res)
            // console.log(res) returns exactly the expected results with the data filled
            // and the tasks array is populated 
            // but on the database there is nothing
        })
        res.status(201).send(req.user)
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

So I get the tasks array populated on the console even after the save callback but nothing on the [db image showing empty tasks array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78ARu.png)

Comment: There is no issue with `req.user` i have used it on other endpoints and it works fine basically it is just the user object as it is returned from a middleware using `User.findOne()`

Comment: Use either `async/await` or `callback`, not the both. Try `await req.user.save(); res.status(201).send(req.user);`

Answer (score 0):

You're working on the user from the request, while you should first find the user from the DB like in your first example (`User.findOne`) and then update and save that model.

Answer (score 0):

Use **.lean()** with your find queries whenever you are about to update the results returned by mongoose. Mongoose by default return instance objects which are immutable by nature. **lean()** method with find returns normal js objects which can be modified/updated.

eg. of using lean()

`const user = await User.findOne({email : req.body.email}).lean();`

You can read more about lean [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Hope this helps :)